# Python sqlalchemy writing data into SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server database using sqlalchemy (with pyodbc) on Python 3.6 in Spyder. I get no error when running:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://admin:pass@SERVERNAME/Databasename')
```

But when I take the data and try to write data into the database:

```
d={'col1':[1,2],'col2':[3,4]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.to_sql('TestTable',con=engine,if_exists='append',index_label='Indx')
```

I get the following error:

> InterfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this
>   error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: While connecting to mssql is sometimes a headache. I prefer creating a data source if I am on Unix system and use driver like FreeTDS.

Comment: That error cannot have come from `to_sql` call but the `engine` call as it is a connection error.